# wait for a callback to end without nesting

Tags: javascript, callback, fabricjs

i'm working with `fabricJS` and it's callback based library to parse `canvas <--> svg` and i'm stuck in the following senario.

```
function A () {
   ...
   B(svgString)
   ...
}

function B (svgString) {
   ...
   fabric.loadSVGFromString(svgString, function(objects, options){
      ...
      canvas.add(..);
      canvas.renderAll();
   });
   ...
}
```

When using this with a simple svg file it workes fine, but when loading an svg with an embedded `base64 png` it jumps to the next instruction in `function A` without completing the `callback` in `function B`

Comment: While the duplicate is nominally about returning a value, the issue it really covers is finishing an asynchronous function before continuing from the calling function (because that is a prerequisite for returning a value from the asynchronous function).

Comment: The principles in the linked solution still apply, although I don't really agree with this issue being closed since in the context of Fabric.js this is a common question. The solution is to have function A pass a callback to function B that gets called when function b completes.